# Изменение размера дисплея в Android

Tags: java, android

Нужна помощь. В android есть такая функция, как работа 1 рукой. Она уменьшает экран для всех приложений в том числе и для главного экрана. Я хочу реализовать что-то похожее в своём приложении, только столкнулся с проблемой. Как получить параметры дисплея я знаю, но как изменять их ни где не нашёл. Желательно, конечно, найти способ без root прав. Спасибо заранее.

[image: Работа 1 рукой в android]

Comment: Я не пишу под Android, но уверен что разрешение экрана не меняется. Скорее всего меняется размер Viewport, рабочей области, из-за чего заново маштабируются элементы. Интерфейс же разрабатывается не под конкретное расширение, а под отношения сторон

Comment: Спасибо за направление, в каком надо думать. Погуглю...